# Loading while a function loads hides everything else on screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flask

I am working on a webapp through flask, and as models loading can be time consuming, I was showing a loading gif until the page loads.
What happens though is that everything else on the screen hides with it.

On my css, is where I have kept the position of my gif to be at the center of the page for now. But I would want it right underneath my submit button on the left. I tried with left and right but it is of no use because everything else hides.

style.css

```
div#loading {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: none;
    background-image: url("../loader.gif");
    cursor: wait;
    }
```

For the function itself, I used a jquery that I put in my html page itself. Here it is:

```
        function loading(){
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#content").hide();       
        }
// ]]></script>
```

I used the loading function on the submit button:

```
<input class="abc" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="loading()" >
```

And finally place a loading div right as the body of my html starts. And I have tried placing this loading div everywhere else on the page as well but it doesnt help.

My entire html code is pasted here. I have been suggested to use fiddle but until the time I fix my code to work in fiddle, here is the html (tried to make it as short as possible, followed by what the screen looks like before and after it starts to load.
ins_html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MASK RCNN</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="loading"></div>
        <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="custom-menu">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
            </button>
        </div>
                <div class="p-4 pt-5">
                <h1><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}" class="logo">Visionet</a></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Computer Vision</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('cv_ins_home') }}">Instance Segmentation</a>
                </li>
                                                    
              </ul>
              
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </nav>

      <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
        <!-- <h2 class="mb-4">Instance Segmentation</h2> -->
        <h1  style= "font-weight: 400; color:#2F5662;" align="center"  >MASK RCNN</h1>
        <p style="color:#458092;">Mask R-CNN is a state-of-the-art model for instance segmentation, developed on top of Faster R-CNN. It is aimed to solve instance segmentation problem in machine learning or computer vision. In other words, it can separate different objects in an image or a video. </p>
        
        <h6>Select an image to upload and predict results</h6>
<!-- <p> -->
    <!-- {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} -->
      <!-- {% if messages %} -->
        <!-- <ul> -->
        <!-- {% for message in messages %} -->
          <!-- <li>{{ message }}</li> -->
        <!-- {% endfor %} -->
        <!-- </ul> -->
      <!-- {% endif %} -->
    <!-- {% endwith %} -->
<!-- </p> -->
<!-- {% if filename %} -->
        <!-- <img class="prediction" src="{{ url_for('cv_ins_display_image', filename=filename) }}" width= "1500" height = "300"> -->
<!-- {% endif %} -->
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <!-- <p> -->
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
        <!-- </p> -->
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input class="abc" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="loading()" >
    </p>
</form>

</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        function loading(){
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#content").hide();       
        }
// ]]></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how the page looks like before clicking submit:
[Page before I click submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WS1i.png)

This is how it looks like once it starts loading:
[After the loading function is triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr9bW.png)

Comment: Can you include working live example to replicate the issue or edit the code?

Comment: @Sambam, make fiddle for it. put your code into fiddle.

Comment: Here I put my code into JS fiddle. Kind of stuck at office with a deadline so unable to properly produce a result after removing my code bits connected to python. But here is the code. As you see in the result, once you click 'submit' what it currently does is hide everything that is on the screen with a loading gif in the very middle of the screen. I need the loading gif to be underneath the submit button while the text alredy there does not hide. https://jsfiddle.net/kfc8bnwu/1/#&togetherjs=3JdnnK81Vv